# Which observer to call imidiately after customer registration to call my custom function?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, customer-account

I am checking in my custom controller if customer is logged in or not if the customer clicks on register after registration it should redirect to my custom controller and continue the process.
I am using **customer_register_success** it is executing but i am **getting blank customer session** in my custom function.Suggest me some solution.
This my custom function

```
 public function getcustomerdata()
   {           
            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
            {
                     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                      echo $customerData->getId();
                       $name = $customerData->getFirstname();

            }
            return $name;

  }
```

My observer function is.

```
 public function doSomething($observer)
   {   
       $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();
        $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

  $session=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
  $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->getCompurl().'state_new/1');
if (!$Customer->getCustomerActivated()) {
}
else{
   //$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($Customer);
   $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args



    $dataarray = Mage::getSingleton("mymodule/session")->getData_array();
    $sampleid=$dataarray['sampleid'];

    $state=$dataarray['state'];
    if($state==1)
    {
      $collection=Mage::getSingleton('mymodule/mymodule')->customisesaved($sampleid);
    if($collection)
    {
        $url=Mage::getUrl('mymodule/mymodule/customshow');
         Mage::log($url,null,"url.log");            
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
         Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
         exit;
    }          

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event to call your function after registration

```
<config><frontend>
<events>
  <customer_register_success>
    <observers>
      <your_module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>your_module/observer</class>
        <method>yourMethod</method>
      </your_module>
    </observers>
  </customer_register_success>
</events></frontend></config>

public function yourMethod($observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I have used this observer but I am getting blank session inside my custom function.

Comment: Please post your code which you are using to get session.

Comment: Please check my update question.

Comment: Try with improved answer.

Comment: check my updated question